# ' - single quotes key in cmd not working

Tags: mysql, windows, cmd, single-quotes

just installed mysql and now trying to work with it (adding databases/tables) through cmd (windows) but when I use single quotes from my keyboard I mean "the key from the left near enter" it does not work. The layout is EN US.
Yes, it works with the GUI, but I want it to work in cmd.

Fixed. Now it works. The problem was in syntax. Always check it even if it works in tutors you follow.
ty)

Comment: What is an example of something that does not work?  MySQL sometimes uses backtick ` rather than ' (e.g. for escaping values)

Comment: Isn't shift plus that key is actually a double quote "?

Comment: So u go into say notepad and u cant get a single quote to appear?